# Firefox KRL extension on yahoo mail

Tags: krl

It looks like the firefox extension might have an issue with the YUI 2.5.2 and 2.7 rich text editor. In the platform Rally when you see any text area, a lot of extra HTML is embedded into it. Rally uses YUI 2.5.2. An easier example to see is in yahoo mail. If you install any kynetx extension and go to create a new mail in a yahoo account, you will see the following output in the compose box as rendered html. It looks like a bug with either YUI or the kynetx app.

```
',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','',' ','
','
','
',' Filters:',' trace',' debug',' info',' warn',' error',' fatal',' all','
','
',' Search: ',' ',' Regex',' Match case',' Disable','
',' ',' ',' Filter',' Highlight all','
','
','
',' Options:',' Log',' Wrap',' Newest at the top',' Scroll to latest',' ',' ',' ','
','
','
','
','
','
',' ',' ','
','
',' ','',''];};var defaultCommandLineFunctions=[];ConsoleAppender=function(){};var consoleAppenderIdCounter=1;ConsoleAppender.prototype=new Appender();ConsoleAppender.prototype.create=function(inPage,container,lazyInit,initiallyMinimized,useDocumentWrite,width,height,focusConsoleWindow){var appender=this;var initialized=false;var consoleWindowCreated=false;var consoleWindowLoaded=false;var consoleClosed=false;var queuedLoggingEvents=[];var isSupported=true;var consoleAppenderId=consoleAppenderIdCounter++;initiallyMinimized=extractBooleanFromParam(initiallyMinimized,this.defaults.initiallyMinimized);lazyInit=extractBooleanFromParam(lazyInit,this.defaults.lazyInit);useDocumentWrite=extractBooleanFromParam(useDocumentWrite,this.defaults.useDocumentWrite);var newestMessageAtTop=this.defaults.newestMessageAtTop;var scrollToLatestMessage=this.defaults.scrollToLatestMessage;width=width?width:this.defaults.width;height=height?height:this.defaults.height;var maxMessages=this.defaults.maxMessages;var showCommandLine=this.defaults.showCommandLine;var commandLineObjectExpansionDepth=this.defaults.commandLineObjectExpansionDepth;var showHideButton=this.defaults.showHideButton;var showCloseButton=this.defaults.showCloseButton;var showLogEntryDeleteButtons=this.defaults.showLogEntryDeleteButtons;this.setLayout(this.defaults.layout);var init,createWindow,safeToAppend,getConsoleWindow,open;var appenderName=inPage?"InPageAppender":"PopUpAppender";var checkCanConfigure=function(configOptionName){if(consoleWindowCreated){handleError(appenderName+": configuration option '"+configOptionName+"' may not be set after the appender has been initialized");return false;} return true;};var consoleWindowExists=function(){return(consoleWindowLoaded&&isSupported&&!consoleClosed);};this.isNewestMessageAtTop=function(){return newestMessageAtTop;};this.setNewestMessageAtTop=function(newestMessageAtTopParam){newestMessageAtTop=bool(newestMessageAtTopParam);if(consoleWindowExists()){getConsoleWindow().setNewestAtTop(newestMessageAtTop);}};this.isScrollToLatestMessage=function(){return scrollToLatestMessage;};this.setScrollToLatestMessage=function(scrollToLatestMessageParam){scrollToLatestMessage=bool(scrollToLatestMessageParam);if(consoleWindowExists()){getConsoleWindow().setScrollToLatest(scrollToLatestMessage);}};this.getWidth=function(){return width;};this.setWidth=function(widthParam){if(checkCanConfigure("width")){width=extractStringFromParam(widthParam,width);}};this.getHeight=function(){return height;};this.setHeight=function(heightParam){if(checkCanConfigure("height")){height=extractStringFromParam(heightParam,height);}};this.getMaxMessages=function(){return maxMessages;};this.setMaxMessages=function(maxMessagesParam){maxMessages=extractIntFromParam(maxMessagesParam,maxMessages);if(consoleWindowExists()){getConsoleWindow().setMaxMessages(maxMessages);}};this.isShowCommandLine=function(){return showCommandLine;};this.setShowCommandLine=function(showCommandLineParam){showCommandLine=bool(showCommandLineParam);if(consoleWindowExists()){getConsoleWindow().setShowCommandLine(showCommandLine);}};this.isShowHideButton=function(){return showHideButton;};this.setShowHideButton=function(showHideButtonParam){showHideButton=bool(showHideButtonParam);if(consoleWindowExists()){getConsoleWindow().setShowHideButton(showHideButton);}};this.isShowCloseButton=function(){return showCloseButton;};this.setShowCloseButton=function(showCloseButtonParam){showCloseButton=bool(showCloseButtonParam);if(consoleWindowExists()){getConsoleWindow().setShowCloseButton(showCloseButton);}};this.getCommandLineObjectExpansionDepth=function(){return commandLineObjectExpansionDepth;};this.setCommandLineObjectExpansionDepth=function(commandLineObjectExpansionDepthParam){commandLineObjectExpansionDepth=extractIntFromParam(commandLineObjectExpansionDepthParam,commandLineObjectExpansionDepth);};var minimized=initiallyMinimized;this.isInitiallyMinimized=function(){return initiallyMinimized;};this.setInitiallyMinimized=function(initiallyMinimizedParam){if(checkCanConfigure("initiallyMinimized")){initiallyMinimized=bool(initiallyMinimizedParam);minimized=initiallyMinimized;}};this.isUseDocumentWrite=function(){return useDocumentWrite;};this.setUseDocumentWrite=function(useDocumentWriteParam){if(checkCanConfigure("useDocumentWrite")){useDocumentWrite=bool(useDocumentWriteParam);}};function QueuedLoggingEvent(loggingEvent,formattedMessage){this.loggingEvent=loggingEvent;this.levelName=loggingEvent.level.name;this.formattedMessage=formattedMessage;} QueuedLoggingEvent.prototype.append=function(){getConsoleWindow().log(this.levelName,this.formattedMessage);};function QueuedGroup(name,initiallyExpanded){this.name=name;this.initiallyExpanded=initiallyExpanded;} QueuedGroup.prototype.append=function(){getConsoleWindow().group(this.name,this.initiallyExpanded);};function QueuedGroupEnd(){} QueuedGroupEnd.prototype.append=function(){getConsoleWindow().groupEnd();};var checkAndAppend=function(){safeToAppend();if(!initialized){init();}else if(consoleClosed&&reopenWhenClosed){createWindow();} if(safeToAppend()){appendQueuedLoggingEvents();}};this.append=function(loggingEvent){if(isSupported){var formattedMessage=appender.getLayout().format(loggingEvent);if(this.getLayout().ignoresThrowable()){formattedMessage+=loggingEvent.getThrowableStrRep();} queuedLoggingEvents.push(new QueuedLoggingEvent(loggingEvent,formattedMessage));checkAndAppend();}};this.group=function(name,initiallyExpanded){if(isSupported){queuedLoggingEvents.push(new QueuedGroup(name,initiallyExpanded));checkAndAppend();}};this.groupEnd=function(){if(isSupported){queuedLoggingEvents.push(new QueuedGroupEnd());checkAndAppend();}};var appendQueuedLoggingEvents=function(){var currentLoggingEvent;while(queuedLoggingEvents.length>0){queuedLoggingEvents.shift().append();} if(focusConsoleWindow){getConsoleWindow().focus();}};this.setAddedToLogger=function(logger){this.loggers.push(logger);if(enabled&&!lazyInit){init();}};this.clear=function(){if(consoleWindowExists()){getConsoleWindow().clearLog();} queuedLoggingEvents.length=0;};this.focus=function(){if(consoleWindowExists()){getConsoleWindow().focus();}};this.focusCommandLine=function(){if(consoleWindowExists()){getConsoleWindow().focusCommandLine();}};this.focusSearch=function(){if(consoleWindowExists()){getConsoleWindow().focusSearch();}};var commandWindow=window;this.getCommandWindow=function(){return commandWindow;};this.setCommandWindow=function(commandWindowParam){commandWindow=commandWindowParam;};this.executeLastCommand=function(){if(consoleWindowExists()){getConsoleWindow().evalLastCommand();}};var commandLayout=new PatternLayout("%m");this.getCommandLayout=function(){return commandLayout;};this.setCommandLayout=function(commandLayoutParam){commandLayout=commandLayoutParam;};this.evalCommandAndAppend=function(expr){var commandReturnValue={appendResult:true,isError:false};var commandOutput="";try{var result,i;if(!commandWindow.eval&&commandWindow.execScript){commandWindow.execScript("null");} var commandLineFunctionsHash={};for(i=0,len=commandLineFunctions.length;i";consoleClosed=false;var iframeDocumentExistsTest=function(win){try{return bool(win)&&bool(win.document);}catch(ex){return false;}};if(iframeDocumentExistsTest(getConsoleWindow())){writeToDocument();}else{pollConsoleWindow(iframeDocumentExistsTest,100,writeToDocument,initErrorMessage);} consoleWindowCreated=true;};createWindow=function(show){if(show||!initiallyMinimized){var pageLoadHandler=function(){if(!container){containerElement=document.createElement("div");containerElement.style.position="fixed";containerElement.style.left="0";containerElement.style.right="0";containerElement.style.bottom="0";document.body.appendChild(containerElement);appender.addCssProperty("borderWidth","1px 0 0 0");appender.addCssProperty("zIndex",1000000);open();}else{try{var el=document.getElementById(container);if(el.nodeType==1){containerElement=el;} open();}catch(ex){handleError("InPageAppender.init: invalid container element '"+container+"' supplied",ex);}}};if(pageLoaded&&container&&container.appendChild){containerElement=container;open();}else if(pageLoaded){pageLoadHandler();}else{log4javascript.addEventListener("load",pageLoadHandler);} windowCreationStarted=true;}};init=function(){createWindow();initialized=true;};getConsoleWindow=function(){var iframe=window.frames[iframeId];if(iframe){return iframe;}};safeToAppend=function(){if(isSupported&&!consoleClosed){if(consoleWindowCreated&&!consoleWindowLoaded&&getConsoleWindow()&&isLoaded(getConsoleWindow())){consoleWindowLoaded=true;} return consoleWindowLoaded;} return false;};}else{var useOldPopUp=appender.defaults.useOldPopUp;var complainAboutPopUpBlocking=appender.defaults.complainAboutPopUpBlocking;var reopenWhenClosed=this.defaults.reopenWhenClosed;this.isUseOldPopUp=function(){return useOldPopUp;};this.setUseOldPopUp=function(useOldPopUpParam){if(checkCanConfigure("useOldPopUp")){useOldPopUp=bool(useOldPopUpParam);}};this.isComplainAboutPopUpBlocking=function(){return complainAboutPopUpBlocking;};this.setComplainAboutPopUpBlocking=function(complainAboutPopUpBlockingParam){if(checkCanConfigure("complainAboutPopUpBlocking")){complainAboutPopUpBlocking=bool(complainAboutPopUpBlockingParam);}};this.isFocusPopUp=function(){return focusConsoleWindow;};this.setFocusPopUp=function(focusPopUpParam){focusConsoleWindow=bool(focusPopUpParam);};this.isReopenWhenClosed=function(){return reopenWhenClosed;};this.setReopenWhenClosed=function(reopenWhenClosedParam){reopenWhenClosed=bool(reopenWhenClosedParam);};this.close=function(){logLog.debug("close "+this);try{popUp.close();this.unload();}catch(ex){}};this.hide=function(){logLog.debug("hide "+this);if(consoleWindowExists()){this.close();}};this.show=function(){logLog.debug("show "+this);if(!consoleWindowCreated){open();}};this.isVisible=function(){return safeToAppend();};var popUp;open=function(){var windowProperties="width="+width+",height="+height+",status,resizable";var windowName="PopUp_"+location.host.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi,"_")+"_"+consoleAppenderId;if(!useOldPopUp||!useDocumentWrite){windowName=windowName+"_"+uniqueId;} var checkPopUpClosed=function(win){if(consoleClosed){return true;}else{try{return bool(win)&&win.closed;}catch(ex){}} return false;};var popUpClosedCallback=function(){if(!consoleClosed){appender.unload();}};function finalInit(){getConsoleWindow().setCloseIfOpenerCloses(!useOldPopUp||!useDocumentWrite);consoleWindowLoadHandler();consoleWindowLoaded=true;appendQueuedLoggingEvents();pollConsoleWindow(checkPopUpClosed,500,popUpClosedCallback,"PopUpAppender.checkPopUpClosed: error checking pop-up window");} try{popUp=window.open(getConsoleUrl(),windowName,windowProperties);consoleClosed=false;consoleWindowCreated=true;if(popUp){if(useDocumentWrite&&useOldPopUp&&isLoaded(popUp)){popUp.mainPageReloaded();finalInit();}else{if(useDocumentWrite){writeHtml(popUp.document);} var popUpLoadedTest=function(win){return bool(win)&&isLoaded(win);};if(isLoaded(popUp)){finalInit();}else{pollConsoleWindow(popUpLoadedTest,100,finalInit,"PopUpAppender.init: unable to create console window");}}}else{isSupported=false;logLog.warn("PopUpAppender.init: pop-ups blocked, please unblock to use PopUpAppender");if(complainAboutPopUpBlocking){handleError("log4javascript: pop-up windows appear to be blocked. Please unblock them to use pop-up logging.");}}}catch(ex){handleError("PopUpAppender.init: error creating pop-up",ex);}};createWindow=function(){if(!initiallyMinimized){open();}};init=function(){createWindow();initialized=true;};getConsoleWindow=function(){return popUp;};safeToAppend=function(){if(isSupported&&!isUndefined(popUp)&&!consoleClosed){if(popUp.closed||(consoleWindowLoaded&&isUndefined(popUp.closed))){appender.unload();logLog.debug("PopUpAppender: pop-up closed");return false;} if(!consoleWindowLoaded&&isLoaded(popUp)){consoleWindowLoaded=true;}} return isSupported&&consoleWindowLoaded&&!consoleClosed;};} this.getConsoleWindow=getConsoleWindow;};ConsoleAppender.addGlobalCommandLineFunction=function(functionName,commandLineFunction){defaultCommandLineFunctions.push([functionName,commandLineFunction]);};function PopUpAppender(lazyInit,initiallyMinimized,useDocumentWrite,width,height){this.create(false,null,lazyInit,initiallyMinimized,useDocumentWrite,width,height,this.defaults.focusPopUp);} PopUpAppender.prototype=new ConsoleAppender();PopUpAppender.prototype.defaults={layout:new PatternLayout("%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p - %m{1}%n"),initiallyMinimized:false,focusPopUp:false,lazyInit:true,useOldPopUp:true,complainAboutPopUpBlocking:true,newestMessageAtTop:false,scrollToLatestMessage:true,width:"600",height:"400",reopenWhenClosed:false,maxMessages:null,showCommandLine:true,commandLineObjectExpansionDepth:1,showHideButton:false,showCloseButton:true,showLogEntryDeleteButtons:true,useDocumentWrite:true};PopUpAppender.prototype.toString=function(){return"PopUpAppender";};log4javascript.PopUpAppender=PopUpAppender;function InPageAppender(container,lazyInit,initiallyMinimized,useDocumentWrite,width,height){this.create(true,container,lazyInit,initiallyMinimized,useDocumentWrite,width,height,false);} InPageAppender.prototype=new ConsoleAppender();InPageAppender.prototype.defaults={layout:new PatternLayout("%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p - %m{1}%n"),initiallyMinimized:false,lazyInit:true,newestMessageAtTop:false,scrollToLatestMessage:true,width:"100%",height:"220px",maxMessages:null,showCommandLine:true,commandLineObjectExpansionDepth:1,showHideButton:false,showCloseButton:false,showLogEntryDeleteButtons:true,useDocumentWrite:true};InPageAppender.prototype.toString=function(){return"InPageAppender";};log4javascript.InPageAppender=InPageAppender;log4javascript.InlineAppender=InPageAppender;})();function padWithSpaces(str,len){if(str.length<([^:]+):"+el.tagName+"[^>]*>","i");if(regex.test(el.outerHTML)){return RegExp.$1.toLowerCase();}} return"";} var lt="<";var gt=">";if(includeRootNode&&rootNode.nodeType!=nodeTypes.DOCUMENT_FRAGMENT_NODE){switch(rootNode.nodeType){case nodeTypes.ELEMENT_NODE:var tagName=rootNode.tagName.toLowerCase();xhtml=startNewLine?newLine+indentation:"";xhtml+=lt;var prefix=getNamespace(rootNode);var hasPrefix=prefix?true:false;if(hasPrefix){xhtml+=prefix+":";} xhtml+=tagName;for(i=0,len=rootNode.attributes.length;i"+newLine;case nodeTypes.DOCUMENT_NODE:xhtml="";for(var i=0,len=rootNode.childNodes.length;i
```

Answer (score 1):

Bug Reports and conflict debugging questions are best answered via email, not as a question here on StackOverflow. Please Email support@kynetx.com with details of any errors, and we'll triage them and address them there.